# Array.Push doesn't work on NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I can't make this code works, i'm trying to generate 5 randoms items from my DB and store them into the array (dato), but when i print it seems to be empty

```
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function (request, response) {
    var dato = new Array();

    for(var i=0;i<7;i++){
        almuerzoSchema.findRandom({}, {}, {limit: 5}, function(err, results) {
            if (!err) {
                results.forEach(function (record) {
                    dato.push(record.nombre);
                });
            }
        });
    }
    console.log(dato);
    response.render('almuerzo.jade',{almuerzovar: dato});
});
```

The console.log(dato) shows:

```
[]
```

if i print "record.nombre" on console.log it shows correctly

Comment: `almuerzoSchema.findRandom` seems `async` to me!

Comment: before the for loop ends, you r trying to print the dato. For loop will run async.

Comment: Please learn how asynchronous programming Node.js works before writing any more code. There are quite a few things wrong with this route, e.g. your for loop is synchronous and is going to cause you quite a few problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like Rayon said, the code is async, so change it to something like this( since async, I am using [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)):

```
/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function (request, response) {
    var dato = new Array(), promises =[];

    for(var i=0;i<7;i++){
        promises.push(promisifiedFindRandom())
    }

    Promise.all(promises).then(function(){
      console.log(dato);
      response.render('almuerzo.jade',{almuerzovar: dato});
    })

    function promisifiedFindRandom(){
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
          almuerzoSchema.findRandom({}, {}, {limit: 5}, function(err, results) {
              if (!err) {
                  results.forEach(function (record) {
                      dato.push(record.nombre);
                  });
                  resolve();
              }else{
                resolve();
              }
          });            
      })
    }
});
```

**Edit**: node v4+ support promise natively, for older versions, you can use polyfill/shim

Comment: `almuerzoSchema.findRandom` is in a `loop` buddy!

Comment: I think you meant `else { reject(err); }`